# Is it possible for a sprite to react to a specific color

Tags: python, pygame

I have a program where a line is drawn if you left-click on the screen, and then after 2 seconds, this line disappears. No new lines can be drawn during these 2 seconds, and if you left-click during these 2 seconds then a white dot will appear instead. This is my code if you want to run it and see for yourself. These white dots disappear after a few seconds. Anyways, is it possible to make a pacman-like sprite "eat" these dots instead of just disappearing by itself? My idea was if there is a white dot present on the screen, then the pacman sprite will be activated and move towards the white dot, then if the sprite reaches the dot, the dot disappears, and the sprite moves back off the screen if there are no more dots left. If there are dots left, then it does straight to the next dot. Is this even possible?

```
from pygame import * 

init()
size = width, height = 650, 650
screen = display.set_mode(size)

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 100, 94)
BLUE = (112, 219, 255)
GREEN = (138, 255, 142)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 158)
color = GREEN
start_time1 = None
start_time2 = None
color = GREEN
col = WHITE

running = True
myClock = time.Clock()
cur_pos = None 
prev_pos = None
start_pos = None
startt_pos = None
lines = 0
start_timer=None


while running:
    def backround():
        draw.circle(screen, YELLOW, (500,120), 75)
        draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (530,120), 50)
    backround()
    for e in event.get(): 
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            if e.button == 1:
                if prev_pos == None:
                    cur_pos = e.pos
                    start_pos = (0,0)
                    draw.line(screen, color, start_pos, cur_pos)
                    lines = lines+1
                    draw.circle(screen, color, e.pos, 5)
                    start_time = time.get_ticks()  #starts timer when the first line is drawn (from 0,0)
                    prev_pos = cur_pos

                if prev_pos != None: 
                    if time.get_ticks() - start_time >= 2000:   #if it has been 2 seconds, draw a line
                        lines = lines+1
                        draw.line(screen, color, prev_pos, e.pos) 
                        draw.circle(screen, color, e.pos, 5)
                        start_time = time.get_ticks()     #restart the timer
                        prevv_pos = prev_pos
                        prev_pos = e.pos



                    if time.get_ticks() - start_time <=2000 and time.get_ticks() - start_time > 0 and time.get_ticks() - start_time <=2500:
                        draw.circle(screen, col, e.pos, 5)



            if e.button == 3:      
                if color == GREEN:
                    color = BLUE
                elif color == BLUE:
                    color = RED
                elif color == RED:
                    color = GREEN              

    if lines >= 1:
        if lines==1: 
            start_timer = time.get_ticks() 

        if time.get_ticks() - start_timer >= 2000:
            if lines == 2:
                screen.fill(BLACK)
                draw.line(screen, color, prevv_pos, prev_pos)    
                lines = lines-1
                draw.circle(screen, color, prevv_pos, 5)
                draw.circle(screen, color, prev_pos, 5)
                backround()




    display.flip()
    myClock.tick(60)
    backround()

quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

> [...] the pacman sprite will be activated and move towards the white dot, then if the sprite reaches the dot, the dot disappears, [...] Is this even possible?

Yes it is, but not with your approach. You'll have to rewrite the entire application.

The key is to redraw the entire screen in every frame. All the object in the scene have to be stored in data structure, in objects and lists respectively [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). The screen is cleared in every frame and the objects and Sprites are draw at there current position and appearance.
With such an approach it it possible to draw dynamically animated objects and to add and remove objects to the scene, by adding and removing the objects from the data structures (lists respectively Groups).

Note, a basic dynamic application has a loop, which continuously redraws the scene. The main application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames). For instance Sprite positions, selected images from sprite sheets for animations, etc.
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (*blit* and *draw* all the objects and Sprites)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# main application loop
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        # [...]

    # update the objects
    # [...]

    # clear the display or draw the background
    window.fill(0)

    # draw the scene   
    # [...]

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop#main.py)</kbd>